# create multiple Data frame by for loop with new name, base on another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

there is a DataFrame in name  df with (rows=250 ,columns=35) ,

I want to create several new DataFrames by for loop base on "df" .

very simplified form of my code is here .

```
# empthy dataframe
my_df = pd.DataFrame() 

for i in range(10):
  my_df[i] = df.iloc[:,3].shift(-i)
  print(my_df[i])
```

but It doesn't work .
displayed error :(  Wrong number of items passed ... , placement implies ....)

Comment: What is `df`? Please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: Aside - Do not flood your global environment with many similarly structured data frames. Instead, create *single* list or dict of many data frame elements. Also avoid growing a data frame in a loop. Pandas users should rarely if ever initialize an empty data frame with `pd.DataFrame()`.